# delete item that is not mine

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

in my web application i have 2 entities `User` and `Ad`, where one user can post many ads, and one ad can be created with only one user, now that i am trying to perform a delete option securely, but it still vulnerable, and a user can still delete an ad which is not his ad, i mean he's not the owner.
the approach that i have did is that before deleting the `ad` i verify if the `id` owner of the ad is equal of the `id` of the man who is connected in the session and that's working fine. now i am asking if there is any better approach that i can follow without that verification trick.

**Ad Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/delete_ad/{id_ad}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String doDeleteAd(@PathVariable("id_ad") Long id_ad, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        Ad ad = adService.findAdById(id_ad);
        if (ad == null) {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alert", "alert-danger");
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("messageDelete","<strong>Oops !</strong> no Ad founded with that id");
            return "redirect:/myads";
        }else {
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
            User u = (User) userDetail;
            if (ad.getPublisher().getId_user() == u.getId_user()) {
                adService.deleteAdById(id_ad);
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alert", "alert-success");
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("messageDelete", "<strong>Done !</strong> Ad deleted succesfully");
                return "redirect:/myads";
            }else {
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("alert", "alert-info");
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("messageDelete", "<strong>Opps !</strong> you are not the owner of the ad");
                return "redirect:/myads";
            }
        }

    }
```

and in `my_ads` view, i have the link below for each ad

```
<a href="delete_ad/${ad.id_ad }" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" >delete</a>
```

Comment: You could also consider using a hashed ID so that nobody on the front end can actually see the ID from the DB - But this would be used alongside what you have already implemented

Comment: @BenLonsdale you mean i should add another token field in my schema to perform the delete based on that token !! isn't

Comment: @saul - What you have is fine and is the conventional way. Take one ID and verify that it is tied to that user before performing the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you're correct in that you will, at some point, have to manually check that the currently authenticated user has permission to delete the record.

I'd argue that having this logic in the controller though is not the best place. What happens if you wish to reuse the delete service elsewhere in the application? I'd suggest either putting the check into the Service layer and throwing an Exception if the user does not have access - or else you could even move it into the `@Entity` class itself by using [JPA lifecycle callbacks](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/event). for instance in the `Ad` class:

```
@PreRemove
void checkPermissions() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetails userDetail = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
    User u = (User) userDetail;

    if( this.getPublisher().getId_user() != u.getId_user() ) {
        throw new SomeCustomNotAuthorizedException("User can't delete record");
    }
}
```

You could then catch this in the Controller and take whatever action is necessary. One downside is that you could not have a "delete by id" method, you'd have to load the object from the database then call delete on the instance.